# How to programmatically manipulate an emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is it possible to programmatically access and manipulate an Android emulator? For example, can I launch an app inside an Android emulator and then click on buttons inside the app from an out-of-the-emulator script?

In web development, we have something like headless browsers such as PhantomJS which we can manipulate it with a script to load web pages, emulate clicks, read output pages, and capture screenshots. Is there something similar to that for the Android platform?

Comment: I have the same question as you and didn't find anything yet. Did you got any update on this?

Comment: Nothing yet. I didn't find any solution, free or paid for this!

Comment: Sad :( - I know that something is out there. For example Jarvee, a social media automation software uses something to post automatically on Instagram, action only available on mobiles...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood your question but I see at least two options for this:

1) using appium (which in this case would be an overkill);

2) using adb commands.

With adb commands you can, for example, install an app on a emulator:

```
adb -s <emulator_id> install <path_to_apk_file>
```

and also send key events:

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_A
```

sources:

http://appium.io/

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb